# Strange behavior of simple UDF in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, udf

I have a hive table, which created using this code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IPRegions (
    ip STRING,
    -- other fields don't matter 
)
```

I need to output each `ip` in reverse order (**yes, it is a very simple problem similar to `SELECT ip FROM IPRegions`**) using self-written UDF.
For doing this, I wrote the following UDF:

```
public class ReverseUDF extends UDF {
    /**
     * Reversing of a string.
     * @param str input string
     * @return reversed string
     */
    public String reverse(String str){
        return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

Than I built the `jar`-file with this UDF and than wrote such query:

```
USE my_base;
add jar Reverser/jar/Reverser.jar;
create temporary function reverse as 'com.lab4udf.ReverseUDF';

select reverse(ip)
from IPRegions;
```

But I cought an exception:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 3:7 Wrong arguments 'ip': No matching method for class com.lab4udf.ReverseUDF with (string).
```

As I saw in many examples, in UDF often used *hadoop types* and not *plain java types*. Than I rewrote and rebuild my UDF:

```
public Text reverse(Text str){
        return new Text(new StringBuilder(str.toString())
                .reverse().toString());
}
```

But it didn't help. **So, where does my error is? How I should change the UDF or the query to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved my problem.

The method, which realize the functionality of UDF (e.g. `reverse()` in my UDF) must be called only `evaluate()` and nothing else!